# F# / Simplest way to validate array length at COMPILE time

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have some scientific project. There are vectors / square matrices of various lengths there. Obviously (for example) a vector of length 2 cannot be added to a vector of length 3 (and so on and so forth). There are several NET libraries, which deal with vectors / matrices. All of them either have generic vectors / matrices OR have some very specific vectors / matrices, which do not suite the needs.

Most, if not all, of these libraries can create a vector from a list or array. Unfortunately, If I mistakenly give an input array of the wrong length, then I will get a vector of the wrong length and then everything will blow up at run time!

I wonder if it is possible to check array length at compile time so that to get a compile error if, let’s say, I try to pass a 5-element array to a vector of length 2 “constructor”. After all, `printfn` does almost that!

F# type providers come to mind, but I am not sure how to apply them here.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at Code Contracts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/code-contracts

Comment: The ref is pure C# and we are talking about F# here. Some of F# things are not "exposable" to NET. For example, erased types (== type providers) and measure units are only visible in F# but cannot be exposed to C#. If you have F# code example, could you, please, post it here. Thanks.

Comment: Have not tried it with F#. The documentation states: "All .NET Framework languages can immediately take advantage of contracts; you do not have to write a special parser or compiler."

Comment: These types of dependent/constrained types require a workaround. I guess TPs are a possibility but do you want to go down that route... It is possible to enforce such constrains by making your constructors private and doing some validation, for example https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/54cfff886669ccab895a

Comment: This is doable in C++ btw :) But I have an idea for something that could work for matrix and vectors. Unfortunately I am at work now so I will need to wait to experiment till I get home. Not sure it will be simple though ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Thanks to the OP for an interesting question. My answer frequency has dropped not because of unwillingness to help but rather that there a few questions that tickles my interest.*

We don't have dependent types in F# and F# doesn't support generics with numerical type arguments (like C++).

However we could create distinct types for different dimensions like `Dim1`, `Dim2` and so on and provide them as type arguments.

This would allow us to have a type signature for `apply` that applies a vector a matrix like this:

```
let apply (m : Matrix<'R, 'C>) (v : Vector<'C>) : Vector<'R> = …
```

The code won't compile unless the columns of the matrix matches the length of the vector. In addition; the resulting vector has the length that is rows of the columns.

One way to do this is defining an interface `IDimension` and some concrete implementions representing the different dimensions.

```
type IDimension =
  interface 
    abstract Size : int
  end

type Dim1 () = class interface IDimension with member x.Size = 1 end end
type Dim2 () = class interface IDimension with member x.Size = 2 end end
```

The vector and the matrix can then be implemented like this

```
type Vector<'Dim  when  'Dim :> IDimension 
                  and   'Dim : (new : unit -> 'Dim)
           > () =
  class
    let dim = new 'Dim()

    let vs  = Array.zeroCreate<float> dim.Size

    member x.Dim    = dim
    member x.Values = vs
  end

type Matrix<'RowDim, 'ColumnDim when  'RowDim :> IDimension 
                                and   'RowDim : (new : unit -> 'RowDim) 
                                and   'ColumnDim :> IDimension 
                                and   'ColumnDim : (new : unit -> 'ColumnDim)
           > () =
  class
    let rowDim    = new 'RowDim()
    let columnDim = new 'ColumnDim()

    let vs  = Array.zeroCreate<float> (rowDim.Size*columnDim.Size)

    member x.RowDim     = rowDim
    member x.ColumnDim  = columnDim
    member x.Values     = vs
  end
```

Finally this allows us to write code like this:

```
let m76 = Matrix<Dim7, Dim6> ()
let v6  = Vector<Dim6> ()
let v7  = apply m76 v6 // Vector<Dim7>

// Doesn't compile because v7 has the wrong dimension
let vv = apply m76 v7
```

If you need a wide range of dimensions (because you have an algebra increments/decrements the dimensions of vectors/matrices) you could support that using some smart variant of church numerals.

If this is usable or not is entirely up the reader I think.

PS.

Perhaps unit of measures could have been used for this as well if they applied to more types than floats.

Comment: This seems close. Thanks. The question remains, how to "enforce", for example, that an array of length 3 e.g. `[| 1.; 2.; 3.; |]` can only be "fed" to a "constructor" (let's say `static member create v`) of vector with `Dim3` but fails for all others. I have only square matrices 2x2, 3x3, and 4x4 and vectors of length 2, 3, 4, so declaring types as Vector2, Vector3, etc... is sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: You can't enforce the array size in compile-time. The size of an array is a runtime concept and F# don't let proofs of an array size flow through the program in compile-time. However, you can create structs that have 1,2,3 ... and so on members for each case. This is typically how small vectors are implemented in .NET as it's too expensive to allocate an array in addition to the object for many small vectors. For small vectors you could check out `System.Numerics.Vectors` as they contain SIMD enabled vectors.

Comment: Also, if you just have these set of limited dimensions you might not need the "Dim" trick at all. Normal concrete classes could do the trick'

Comment: They do, except the initialization. Both of the following are valid at compile time: `[| 1.; 2.; 3.; |] |> Vector3.create` and `[| 1.; 2.; 3.; |] |> Vector2.create`. The second one will either fail at run time (if I put a validation in `Vector2.create`) or fail later at run time when I try, let's say, add two `Vector2`, one of which has invalid data. I want `[| 1.; 2.; 3.; |] |> Vector2.create` (or something like that) fail at compile time :)

Comment: If you have a constructor that accepts a tuple then you can't pass in the wrong number of arguments. At the time of calling the ctor you might need to have a runtime check you believe in (tests or code inspection). F* I believe can make use of proofs in compile-time but not F#.

Answer (score 2):

The general term for what you're looking for is [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), but F# does not support them.

I've seen [an experiment](https://github.com/caindy/DependentTypesProvider) in using type providers to mimic one particular flavor of dependent types (constraining the domain of a primitive type), but I wouldn't expect it to be possible to achieve what you want using type providers in their current form. They seem to be too whimsical for that.

Print format strings appear to be doing that (and in fact printers are a "Hello World" application for dependent types), but actually they work because they get special treatment by the compiler, and the mechanism for that is not extensible.

You're doomed to ensure correct lengths at runtime.

My best bet would be to use structs to encode actual vectors and ensure correctness on the API level that way, map them to arrays at the point where you're interacting with those matrix algebra libraries, then map the results back to structs with ample assertions when done.

Comment: If that experiment can constrain strings (arrays of characters) to have some specific length, then it should be possible to tweak it to constrain an array of floats to have a specific length. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov: The difference is that with strings you're looking at compile time literals, and as mentioned in the other answer's comments, array length is not a compile time concept. Maybe I'm missing something and you can get what you want this way, but my hunch is that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Justanothermetaprogrammer qualifies as an answer. Here is how it works in the real example. The matrix implementation in the example is based on `MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra`:

```
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

type RealMatrix2x2 = 
    | RealMatrix2x2 of Matrix<double>

    static member private createInternal (a : #seq<#seq<double>>) = 
        matrix a |> RealMatrix2x2

    static member create
        (
            (a11, a12),
            (a21, a22)
        ) = 
        RealMatrix2x2.createInternal 
            [| 
                [| a11; a12|]
                [| a21; a22|]
            |]


let m2 = 
        (
            (1., 2.),
            (3., 4.)
        )
        |> RealMatrix2x2.create
```

The tuple signatures and "re-mapping" into `#seq<#seq<double>>` can be easily code-generated using, for example, Excel or any other convenient tool for as many dimensions as necessary. In fact, the whole class along with any other necessary operator overrides (like multiplication of `RealMatrix2x2` by `RealMatrix2x2`, ...) can be code generated for all necessary dimensions.